# Mandate or Mission Statement of US Space Command

Tags: united-states, space

In August of 2019, the re-establishment of the [US Space Command](https://news.wttw.com/2019/08/29/trump-s-dream-space-force-moves-one-step-closer-reality?mini=2019-07).  While I understand that this a unified force command under the US Strategic Command at the Pentagon, what is the official mandate or mission statement of the Command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mandate was contained within the [memorandum](https://www.whitehouse.gov/briefings-statements/text-memorandum-president-secretary-defense-regarding-establishment-united-states-space-command/) issued by President Trump to the Secretary of Defense

> I assign to United States Space Command:  (1) all the general responsibilities of a Unified Combatant Command; (2) the space‑related responsibilities previously assigned to the Commander, United States Strategic Command; and (3) the responsibilities of Joint Force Provider and Joint Force Trainer for Space Operations Forces.

The [mission statement](https://www.spacecom.mil/About/Fact-Sheets-Editor/Article/1948216/united-states-space-command-fact-sheet/) on the website states

> The USSPACECOM mission is to deter aggression and conflict, defend U.S. and allied freedom of action, deliver space combat power for the Joint/Combined force, and develop joint warfighters to advance U.S. and allied interests in, from, and through the space domain.
>
> The USSPACECOM mission involves four distinct areas of focus:
>
> 1. Deter Aggression/Conflict:  USSPACECOM strengthens our national deterrence through the provision of space warfighting options that preserve U.S. and allied competitive advantage, promote security and stability.
> 2. Defend U.S./Allied Interests:  If deterrence fails, USSPACECOM, in coordination with allied and joint force commanders and inter-agency partners, will lead the protection and defense of our combined interests in the space domain.
> 3. Deliver Space Combat Power:  USSPACECOM is committed to preserving and expanding space combat power to enable joint and combined force success.
> 4. Develop Ready and Lethal Joint Warfighters:  USSPACECOM will improve the development of joint space operations forces and capabilities to enhance space warfighting readiness and lethality while accelerating the integration of space capabilities into other warfighting forces.